# MySQL: Joining a table to itself, eliminating duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a query that connects a table to itself. The results contain duplicate rows (sort of). The objective of this query is to produce a list of products most frequently purchased together. Consider this query:

```
SELECT o1.ITEM
,o2.ITEM as ITEM2
,o3.ITEM AS ITEM3
,count(DISTINCT o1.ORDERNUM) as oCount
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN orders o2 ON o2.ORDERNUM = o1.ORDERNUM AND o2.ITEM != o1.ITEM
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o3 ON o3.ORDERNUM = o1.ORDERNUM AND o3.ITEM != o2.ITEM AND o3.ITEM != o1.ITEM
GROUP BY o1.ITEM, o2.ITEM, o3.ITEM
ORDER BY oCount DESC
```

And the first 12 results:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| ITEM        | ITEM2       | ITEM3       | oCount |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 02B13.04.GP | 77A04.10    | 45A04.04.GP |     54 |
| 02B13.04.GP | 45A04.04.GP | 77A04.10    |     54 |
| 77A04.10    | 45A04.04.GP | 02B13.04.GP |     54 |
| 45A04.04.GP | 02B13.04.GP | 77A04.10    |     54 |
| 77A04.10    | 02B13.04.GP | 45A04.04.GP |     54 |
| 45A04.04.GP | 77A04.10    | 02B13.04.GP |     54 |
| 57B01.01.GP | 57B01.11.GP | 57B01.10.GP |     12 |
| 57B01.10.GP | 57B01.11.GP | 57B01.01.GP |     12 |
| 57B01.01.GP | 57B01.10.GP | 57B01.11.GP |     12 |
| 57B01.10.GP | 57B01.01.GP | 57B01.11.GP |     12 |
| 57B01.11.GP | 57B01.10.GP | 57B01.01.GP |     12 |
| 57B01.11.GP | 57B01.01.GP | 57B01.10.GP |     12 |
```

Note that the first 6 results are the same connections, in a different order. The second 6 results have the same issue (and this continues throughout the results). My goal is to have a single record for each item group, not a single row for each combination of each item group.

**How can I avoid these repeated results?**

Also any advice on a more efficient approach to this query would be welcome (I'd like to add an additional join, but with 1,000,000 orders the resource requirements are getting out of hand).

================================================

**EDIT: To answer Darshan's questions**

Can you share the table structure:

The table contains the lines for all the orders. If an order contains multiple products, there will be a line for each product (multiple lines for a given order). The only columns of concern in this query are:

```
ORDERNUM CHAR : Order Number
ITEM CHAR : SKU for the item
QTY INT : Quantity purchased
ORDDATE DATETIME : Order Date
```

Results returned: All I need is what I listed in the result sample above. The objective is to get a list of the products that are purchased together the most often.

Comment: Could you share the structure of Order table and expected output?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I edited the question to include answers to your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to eliminate duplicated rows regardless of the position; one trick, since you always have all the combinations of items is to filter the results according to a predicate that says item1 < item2 < item3

Here is a possible solution:

```
SELECT a.item, b.item, c.item, count(*)
from `orders` a left join orders b
on a.ordernum = b.ordernum and a.item <> b.item
left join orders c on a.ordernum = c.ordernum
and a.item <> c.item and b.item <> c.item
where a.item < b.item and b.item < c.item
group by a.item, b.item, c.item
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Thanks @eugenio that did the job!